# Is it possible to use FillBetweenItem to fill between two PlotCurveItem's in pyqtgraph?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqtgraph

I'm attempting to fill between two curves that were created using PlotCurveItem in pyqtgraph.

```
            phigh = self.p2.addItem(pg.PlotCurveItem(x, y, pen = 'k'))           
            plow = self.p2.addItem(pg.PlotCurveItem(x, yy, pen = 'k'))           
            pfill = pg.FillBetweenItem(phigh, plow, brush = br)
            self.p2.addItem(pfill)
```

The curve items are plotting properly however there is no fill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This fixed it.

```
            phigh = pg.PlotCurveItem(x, y, pen = 'k')           
            plow = pg.PlotCurveItem(x, yy, pen = 'k')                  
            pfill = pg.FillBetweenItem(ph, plow, brush = br)
            self.p2.addItem(ph)
            self.p2.addItem(plow)
            self.p2.addItem(pfill)
```